# Error in train and predict of my opencv program

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Empty training data was given. You'll
>   need more than one sample to learn a model.) in train, file
>   C:/slave/WinInstallerMegaPack/src/opencv/modules/contrib/src/facerec.cpp,
>   line 316

I get the above error when I try to run the below program. My intension is to give some input images and check the `train()` and `predict()` functions of opencv. Is anything wrong in the below code snippet?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    const char * trainImage[6] = { "c:\\train\\00000000.jpg", "c:\\train\\00000001.jpg", "c:\\train\\00000002.jpg", "c:\\train\\00000003.jpg", "c:\\train\\00000004.jpg", "c:\\train\\00000005.jpg" };

    int imglabel[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};        
    vector<Mat> img = vector<Mat>();
    vector<int> label = vector<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i >= 5; i++) {
        img.push_back(imread(trainImage[i], 0));
        label.push_back(imglabel[i]);
    }

    Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
    model->train(img, label);
    model->save("c:\\train\\file.yaml");

    // Testing...
    model->load("c:\\train\\file.yaml");
    Mat testsample = imread("c:\\test\\00000000.jpg", -1);

    int PredictLabel = -1;
    double confidence = 0.0;

    model->predict(testsample, PredictLabel, confidence);
    cout << PredictLabel;
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Provide more training samples for each label.

See code sample in [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html#void%20FaceRecognizer%3a%3atrain%28InputArrayOfArrays%20src,%20InputArray%20labels%29%20=%200):

```
// images for first person
images.push_back(imread("person0/0.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)); labels.push_back(0);
images.push_back(imread("person0/1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)); labels.push_back(0);
images.push_back(imread("person0/2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)); labels.push_back(0);
// images for second person
images.push_back(imread("person1/0.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)); labels.push_back(1);
images.push_back(imread("person1/1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)); labels.push_back(1);
images.push_back(imread("person1/2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)); labels.push_back(1);
```

Also your `for` loop condition is wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
```

And test image should be loaded grayscale:

```
Mat testsample = imread("test.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I did as you said now I get the error OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (File can't be opened for writing!) in load, file C:/slave/WinInstallerMegaPack/src/opencv/modules/contrib/src/facerec.cpp, line 304

Comment: maybe you have no access to that folder, try to change path to `"file.yml"`